# 403 denied access with Spring Security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm building an application with Spring and I used Spring Security. The thing is that I can't make it right with the authorizeRequests chain. I have 3 roles:

ROLE_RH has access to the views with the context RH

ROLE_GP has access to the views with the context GP

ROLE_SUPER has access to all the views, including the context RH and GP

My authorizeRequests chain looks like this:

```
    http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/bootstrap/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/RH/**").hasRole("RH")
        .antMatchers("/GP/**").hasRole("GP")
        .antMatchers("/**").hasRole("SUPER")
        .and()
    .formLogin()
        .failureUrl("/login?error")
        .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("nombreUsuario").passwordParameter("contrasena")
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/default")
        .and()
    .logout()
        .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
        .permitAll()
        .and().csrf()
        .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403");
```

But when I'm logged as ROLE_SUPER I can't access to RH and GP views, I got access denied every single time.
I tried changing the .antMatcher of ROLE_SUPER to this

```
.antMatchers("/GP/**","/RH/**","/DB/**").hasRole("SUPER")
```

And when I try to log as ROLE_GP or ROLE_RH I get access denied to their views too. 
Roles can't share same context? When ROLE_SUPER works ROLE_GP and ROLE_RH don't and the other way around. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research and the solution that worked for me:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/bootstrap/**", "/dist/**", "/plugins/**").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/DB/**").hasRole("SUPER") 
        .antMatchers("/RH/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER') or hasRole('ROLE_RH')")
        .antMatchers("/GP/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER') or hasRole('ROLE_GP')")
```